# How to make (output file) take the name from (input mp3 file) in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using Windows 7
Here is my batch file.
This batch file combines mp3 and png. By adding album art to the audio file.

```
@echo off
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color a
set a=Your_files\*.mp3
set aa=Your_files\*.png
set b="Result\%%~na.mp3"
set c=ffmpeg
set f=-map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (Front)"
for %%a in (%a%) do !set mp3="%%a"!
for %%s in (%aa%) do !set png="%%s"!
%c% -y -i %mp3% -i %png% %f% %b%
exit
```

When I write this (%% ~ na.mp3) he doesn't know where to get the title from.
So it outputs this as the filename (% ~ na.mp3).

```
set a=Your_files\*.mp3
set aa=Your_files\*.png
set b="Result\%%~na.mp3"
```

[That's what I want. Open me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF3gL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**
Here is the solution to my problem..

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color a
set a=Your_files\*.mp3
set aa=Your_files\*.png
set b="Result\%%~na.mp3"
set c=ffmpeg
set f=-map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (Front)"
for %%s in (%aa%) do !set png="%%s"!
for %%a in (%a%) do (%c% -y -i "%%a" -i %png% %f% %b%)
exit
```